# Is this 36 character long string a hash

Tags: hash, forensics

I found this string
`b2335332-d28f-449b-8d00-80a550b43046`
Do you think it´s a hash?
If yes any idea which one and if not any other ideas what it could be?

Comment: This question if off-topic on Security SE. I suggest to close. it.

Comment: What you posted is 32 hexadecimal characters.  So, that's 128 bits (each hexadecimal character represents 4 bits).  The most common type of 128-bit hash is MD5.  So, if it's a hash, it's most likely an MD5 hash.

Answer (score 5):

> I found this string
> `b2335332-d28f-449b-8d00-80a550b43046`
> Do you think it´s a hash?
> If yes any idea which one and if not any other ideas what it could be?

It looks like a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

See, in particular, the section from the linked article titled "Format," which states: "...the 16 octets of a UUID are represented as 32 hexadecimal (base-16) digits, displayed in five groups separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36 characters (32 hexadecimal characters and 4 hyphens)."

The version digit is 4, so this is (supposed to be) [a random value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)), not a hash.